# Tiling with QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, image, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

I'm creating a image visualizer that open large images(2gb+) in Qt.
I'm doing this by breaking the large image into several tiles of 512X512. I then load a QGraphicsScene of the original image size and use addPixmap to add each tile onto the QGraphic Scene. So ultimately it looks like a huge image to the end user when in fact it is a continuous array of smaller images stuck together on the scene.First of is this a good approach?

Trying to load all the tiles onto the scene takes up a lot of memory. So I'm thinking of only loading the tiles that are visible in the view. I've already managed to subclass QGraphicsScene and override its drag event thus enabling me to know which tiles need to be loaded next based on movement. My problem is tracking movement on the scrollbars. Is there any way I can create an event that get called every time the scrollbar moves. Subclassing QGraphicsView in not an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`QGraphicsScene` is smart enough not to render what isn't visible, so here's what you need to do:

Instead of loading and adding pixmaps, add classes that *wrap* the pixmap, and only load it when they are first rendered. (Computer scientists like to call this a "proxy pattern"). You could then unload the pixmap based on a timer. (They would be transparently re-loaded if unloaded too soon.) You could even notify this proxy path of the current zoom level, so that it loads lower resolution images when they will be rendered smaller.

---

Edit: here's some code to get you started. Note that everything that `QGraphicsScene` draws is a `QGraphicsItem`, (if you call `::addPixmap`, it's converted to a `...GraphicsItem` behind the scenes), so that's what you want to subclass:

(I haven't even compiled this, so "caveat lector", but it's doing the right thing ;)

```
class MyPixmap: public QGraphicsItem{
    public:
        // make sure to set `item` to nullptr in the constructor
        MyPixmap()
            : QGraphicsItem(...), item(nullptr){
        }

        // you will need to add a destructor
        // (and probably a copy constructor and assignment operator)

        QRectF boundingRect() const{
            // return the size
            return QRectF( ... );
        }

        void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                   QWidget *widget){
            if(nullptr == item){
                // load item:
                item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem( ... );
            }
            item->paint(painter, option, widget);
        }

     private:
         // you'll probably want to store information about where you're
         // going to load the pixmap from, too

         QGraphicsPixmapItem *item;
};
```

then you can add your pixmaps to the `QGraphicsScene` using `QGraphicsScene::addItem(...)`

Comment: This is great. Would save a hell of a lot of work. I was wondering though would this be slow or stuttering while scrolling. What I had originally planned was to keep track of what the user is viewing using mouse and scrollbar event and then load up surrounding tiles and place them on the scene in advance using a separate thread. As the user moves through the scene the background thread would simply load and unload tiles accordingly. Does QGraphicsItem paint already do this in the background?

Comment: If you wanted to load in a separate thread you'd have to send a signal from your paint event to a worker thread instead of loading the image, and then whenever paint is called draw some sort of blank image until the thread has loaded it. You *could* return a large than actual size for the `boundingRect()` to trigger paint events before tiles are actually visible. But this might have other side effects if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks you've been a great help. I got tile loading almost done. Now what's the best way to unload the tiles. From what I understood from your previous post, you suggested I run a timer that destroys every PixmapItem in the scene and sets it to NULL every few seconds. And since the paint method gets called for every update, it would automatically restore the tiles that are currently being viewed. Am I right?

Comment: np :) That was my suggestion, not sure if there's a better way, --- you could probably use quite a long timer, or a timer based on how many have been allocated, or you could maybe limit the number that are loaded, and if you need to load a new one, unload the oldest.

Comment: @sleeping QGraphicsItem has an isVisible member function. You could probably use that to check for when to unload your tile.

Comment: @RedX I considered that but scanning around 40000 tiles for isVisible event isn't very efficient and now that I think over it neither is destroying every PixmapItem in the scene. One solution I thought of was to keep all the loaded tiles in a fixed size queue. Each time a new tile loads up an old tile get destroyed. A 2nd approach I though of is to connect the movement of the scrollbars to loading and unloading. If I move the scrollbar up the tiles down below get unloaded. If I move it down the tiles on the top get unloaded. I think this might be more efficient.

Comment: @sleeping.ninja Would you be available to talk about how you implemented this? I am facing the same situation - wanting to load a large image using some kind of tiling with a QGraphicsItem

Comment: yeah sure. How do you want to communicate? Send me your email

Answer (score 6):

Although an answer has already been chosen, I'd like to express my opinion.

I don't like the selected answer, especially because of that usage of timers. A timer to unload the pixmaps? Say that the user actually wants to take a good look at the image, and after a couple of seconds - bam, the image is unloaded, he will have to do something in order the image to reappear. Or may be you will put another timer, that loads the pixmaps after another couple of seconds? Or you will check among your thousand of items if they are visible? Not only is this very very irritating and wrong, but that means that your program will be using resources all the time. Say the user minimizes you program and plays a movie, he will wonder why on earth my movie is freezing every couple of seconds...

Well, if I misunderstood the proposed idea of using timers, execuse me.

Actually the idea that mmutz suggested is better. It reminded me of the [Mandelbrot example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/threads-mandelbrot.html). Take a look at it. Instead of calculating what to draw you can rewrite this part to loading that part of the image that you need to show.

In conclusion I will propose another solution using QGraphicsView in a much simpler way:

1) check the size of the image without loading the image (use QImageReader)

2) make your scene's size equal to that of the image

3) instead of using pixmap items reimplement the DrawBackground() function. One of the parameters will give you the new exposed rectangle - meaning that if the user scrolls just a little bit, you will load and draw only this new part(to load only part of an image use setClipRect() and then read() methods of the QImageReader class). If there are some transformations you can get them from the other parameter(which is QPainter) and apply them to the image before you draw it.

In my opinion the best solution will be to combine my solution with the threading shown in the [Mandelbrot example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/threads-mandelbrot.html).

The only problem that I can think of now is if the user zooms out with a big scale factor. Then you will need a lot of resources for some time to load and scale a huge image. Well I see now that there is some function of the QImageReader that I haven't tried yet - setScaledSize(), which maybe do just what we need - if you set a scale size and then load the image maybe it won't load first the entire image – try it. Another way is just to limit the scale factor, a thing that you should do anyway if you stick to the method with the pixmap items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually Autopulated's suggestion of subclassing QGraphicsItem and overloading paint worked out really well. It means that I can paste empty QGraphicsItem's onto the scene. This shouldn't take up much memory. The paint method of a QGraphicsItem get called only when it is visible inside the view. So I've implemented it such that your actual image data only gets loaded into the object when it is visible in the view. So loading tiles is pretty much taken care off. Now the only problem remain in unloading unused tiles.

Comment: After considering several approaches I think I'm going to use a Queue approach to tiles. I'll maintain a queue of constant size that takes in a new tiles and deletes old tiles (FIFO). This should be much better than using a timer. What do you think?

Comment: And I've considered the zooming problem early on. What I've planned to do is construct tiles of several zoom levels(Like tile level 0 -> 100% level 1->50% etc). As long as the user is zooming between 50-100% zoom I'll use the setScale fucntion in QGraphicsView (Another advantage of using QGraphicsView over QAbstractScrollArea). Once the user goes into the 25-50% zoom level a new set of tiles are loaded (level 1 tiles) and the scale is set back to 1. In short pyramiding should solve this. Also overriding paint in QGraphicsItem allows me to seamlessly integrate pyramided-zooming

Comment: If your interested take a look at 40000 chip example. Take a look at the level of detail variable inside the overridden paint function. Some brilliant stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you absolutely need the view to be a `QGraphicsView` (e.g. because you place other objects on top of the large background pixmap), I'd really recommend just subclassing `QAbstractScrollArea` and reimplementing `scrollContentsBy()` and `paintEvent()`.

Add in a LRU cache of pixmaps (see `QPixmapCache` for inspiration, though that one is global), and make the `paintEvent()` pull used pixmaps to the front, and be set.

If this sounds like more work than the `QGraphicsItem`, believe me, it's not :)

Comment: Well from a future development point of view, I will need to add a vector overlay over my raster data at some point of time. So I'll need a lot of shape drawing functions to draw lines and polygons. QGraphicsView seems to have a lot of stuff available out of the box. So I'm sticking with QGraphicsView for now