# Reading the same fragment of a large image from disk multiple times without closing the file

Tags: c++, image, qt

**UPD**. Okay, so since my question was met mostly with confusion, I'll try to fix it by narrowing the problem down to the essentials.

**Given:**

- a large image of several Gb, call it `img.jpg`(`.png`/`.bmp`);
- the coordinates of a small fragment on the image `rect = QRect(x,y,w,h)`;

**Write:**

- a function that loads the fragment `rect` from the image on a disk to a `QPixmap`; the function is to be called frequently.

**Attempted solution and problems:**

- the first solution was to use `QImageReader` that has a method `setClipRect(QRect)` to specify a region on the image to be loaded. Perfect, right? Well, the problem is that the method `read()` will return `QImage` only when it's called for the first time. After that, it will be returning empty images with an error message "Unable to read image data". Rewinding the `QIOReader` that `QImageReader` uses to zero doesn't help. Creating the `QImageReader` again costs dearly in performance.

**Links:**

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459278/read-image-files-with-qimagereader-using-qtconcurrent)'s the question from 2011 with essentially the same problem (my question might as well be a duplicate). A person attempts to do the same thing I do and faces the same problem. He asks why his reader gives him "Unable to read image data", well because it doesn't read twice, and it's unclear how to fix it.
2. [Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/34504/solved-qimagereader-strange-behaviour) they ask basically the same question and the solution is to rewind the QIODevice by calling `reader->device()->seek(0);`. The problem is that it doesn't work: after rewinding the device `reader->read()` still returns empty `QImage`s and produce an error message "Unable to read image data".
3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797908/handling-very-large-images-in-qt), [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45914-QGraphicsView-and-many-QGraphicsPixmapItem-items-memory-managment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927665/tiling-with-qgraphicsscene-and-qgraphicsview) are posts that discuss the problem of loading large images in tiles in Qt that helped me implement my current solution.

Below is the original post with more details.

---

I'm writing a widget that loads an image fragmentarily and displays it in `QGraphicsScene` with tiles that can be loaded and unloaded depending on their visibility in a viewport. Tiles show a placeholder when they are unloaded and they load a corresponding fragment into a `QPixmap` on demand. The widget is supposed to be able to open images of sizes up to several gigabytes without taking much memory.

I was planning to make each tile have the image opened and ready to be read from a certain place. I'm using a `QImageReader` that allows you to set a rectangle defining the area of the image to be loaded. But it turned out that after setting a rectangle I can only read the image **once**. In order to load it again, I have to create a new instance of `QImageReader` that would open the file **anew**. I tried opening ~2Gb images with 256x256 tiles and it loads very slowly: on my computer, it takes about 30 sec to load one HD screen.

This is the code that I currently use to load tiles:

```
void TileLoader::load(int posx, int posy, int w, int h, QString filename) {
    QImageReader reader(filename);
    QRect tile(posx, posy, w, h);
    reader.setClipRect(tile);
    QImage image(w, h, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    reader.read(&image);
    emit tileLoaded(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
```

Instead of creating `QImageReader` instance every time, I was hoping to pass the existing one as an argument. But unfortunately it works only once, so `QImageReader` is not the way to go. But what is?

I can also recreate the slow loading with regular images like ~1000x1000 pixels if I set tile size at 16x16. I can see little tiles unfolding an image in front of my eyes in a wave-like motion for about 10 sec, which is a beautiful thing to see by itself, but completely impractical in terms of the task at hand.

[image]

[image]

So the question is: is there a way to keep my image file open for the whole time a tile exists, so it can quickly read parts of it?

Comment: Are you testing an optimized build or a debug build? Don't bother testing un-optimized builds for performance.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I have the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3` flag set. But it seems to me that it's not about optimization, rather about a lot of redundant operations with the disk. I'm looking for a way to read fragments of an image more than once without having to close and open it every time.

Comment: Sure. But step 1 is just checking that you are *at least* testing an optimised build.

Comment: According to the doc you can read more than once in `QImageReader` : *calling read() repeatedly will return the next frame*. What have you tried ? It does not work to set a different `setScaledClipRect` ? Please be more specific about what is not working when you try to use the same instance of `QImageReader`.

Comment: If this does not work, you can probably optimize by giving a QIODevice to your `QImageReader` instead of the filename, so you can open the file yourself and keep the instance in memory.

Comment: @ymoreau, *"calling read() repeatedly will return the next frame"* is about images with multiple frames, i.e. animation. In my case, I only have one frame. Every time you call read() after the first call, it returns an image with all zeros (black), even if you call seek(0) on QIODevice. I tried feeding QImageReader a QFile object -- same results on all accounts

Comment: Just to clarify.  When you say `"I tried opening ~2Gb images ..."` does the 2Gb refer to the actual size of the JPEG file on disk or the approximate size of the decompressed raw image data -- i.e. `num. channels x width x height` ?

Comment: @G.M., in that particular case, 2Gb is the actual size of the JPEG file on disk, and the image dimensions are 54940x29195 with 3 color channels.